# return quotes to html

Tags: php, regex, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm parsing web-page that contains html tags without quotes. Something like this `<FONT COLOR=#FF0000>` but I need `<FONT COLOR="#FF0000">`  How return quotes to html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace('/(?<==)([^\s>]+)/', '"$1"', $handle);
```